# pass checkedlistbox checked item values to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox. I want to be able to select n items from it, and then pass those item values (as Text in the CheckedListBox) into a sproc. I have no issue with connecting to the DB and calling the sproc. I just need to figure out how to assign the selected item values to a variable. What data type should I use?

I think all I need to figure out is this part:

```
string listingId = checkedListBoxBids.CheckedItems.ToString();
```

I pasted my code below. The first 2 methods call the sprocs I use; the 3rd method fires one of the 2 sprocs based on some radio button selections / clicking on a confirm button.

```
// marks selected listbox item as 'Won'
private void MarkItemAsWon(string itemWon)
{
    string listingId = checkedListBoxBids.CheckedItems.ToString();
    //string listingId = checkedListBoxBids.Text.ToString();

    // connection string
    string cnWatermelon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Watermelon.Properties.Settings.watermelonsConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection watermelonConn = new SqlConnection(cnWatermelon);

    SqlCommand markItemAsWonCommand = new SqlCommand();

    markItemAsWonCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    markItemAsWonCommand.CommandText = "dbo.MarkItemAsWon";

    markItemAsWonCommand.Parameters.Add("@ListingID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = listingId;

    SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        markItemAsWonCommand.Connection = watermelonConn;

        watermelonConn.Open();

        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand = markItemAsWonCommand;

        MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception exc_PROCESS)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc_PROCESS.ToString(), "Error message",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
    finally
    {
        watermelonConn.Close();
    }
}


// marks selected listbox item as 'Lost'
private void MarkItemAsLost(string itemLost)
{
    string listingId = checkedListBoxBids.CheckedItems.ToString();
    //string listingId = checkedListBoxBids.Text.ToString();

    // connection string
    string cnWatermelon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Watermelon.Properties.Settings.watermelonsConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection watermelonConn = new SqlConnection(cnWatermelon);

    SqlCommand markItemAsLostCommand = new SqlCommand();

    markItemAsLostCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    markItemAsLostCommand.CommandText = "dbo.MarkItemAsLost";

    markItemAsLostCommand.Parameters.Add("@ListingID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = listingId;

    SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        markItemAsLostCommand.Connection = watermelonConn;

        watermelonConn.Open();

        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand = markItemAsLostCommand;

        MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception exc_PROCESS)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc_PROCESS.ToString(), "Error message",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
    finally
    {
        watermelonConn.Close();
    }
}



// reads the option selected in the "Won?" groupbox and marks selected item as either 'Won' or 'Lost', then refreshes the checkedlistbox items
private void buttonWonConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string listingId = checkedListBoxBids.CheckedItems.ToString();

    if (radioButtonWonYes.Checked == true)
    {

        //foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBoxBids.CheckedItems)
        //{

        //    // show selected items in messagebox
        //    //MessageBox.Show("Item with title: \"" + itemChecked.ToString());

        //    MarkItemAsWon(itemChecked.ToString());
        //}


        MarkItemAsWon(listingId.ToString());

        PopulateBidItems();
        PopulateWonItems();
    }
    else
    {
        MarkItemAsLost(listingId.ToString());

        PopulateBidItems(); 
        PopulateWonItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: how you bind checkedListBoxBids?

Comment: If you have selected multiple items what would you want to pass to SP?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [table-value parameters](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/). That way you could send a table prameter to the database with all the selected items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkedListBoxBids.CheckedItems` will return collection of checked items.  based on your need you can get each checked item or just one of item like below

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBoxBids.CheckedItems)
{
     DataRowView item = itemChecked as DataRowView;
     string listingID= item["ListingID"];

}
```

assume you bind as below

```
checkedListBoxBids.DataSource = dt;
checkedListBoxBids.DisplayMember = "ListingName";
checkedListBoxBids.ValueMember = "ListingID";
```